# Proposal: Adding the text "in text form" in the close reason

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

**Situation:**

We can see many posts containing links to code / images (snapshot) of code. These posts are bad because

1. The code in the question (image) cannot be indexed for future search.
2. Tough to copy-paste the code to reproduce the error.

Currently, we have a close reason which says:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

I propose, please modify the reason to add a hint about the need for *"text-based code"* so that this close reason can be used for the posts adding screenshots / links for code.

**Proposal:**

*Modified text emphasized*

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary ***[in text form](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)*** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Is not "**in the question itself**" enough?

Comment: Ideally **in text form** should be a link to the [code formatting advanced help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: @YSC No, a screen shot would also appear _in the question itself_, though it's not wanted.

Comment: Good proposal. +1, I support it fully.

Comment: Yes, why not expand the paragraph full of text that no one reads anyway. Do you think this will actually solve the problem?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I interpret "in the question itself" to be in contradiction with the use of an image, since images are hosted on imgur.com. Ok for a precision then.

Comment: Are the questions that post the code as an image actually staying open and being well received by the community currently?  Do the authors actually push back when they're told that they need to post code as text?  I haven't really seen much of either of those things.  Sounds like you're trying to fix something that's not really a problem.

Comment: @Servy At least, this will save me from leaving a separate comment asking for the text version of the code every time.

Comment: @YSC "Is not "in the question itself" enough?" apparently not.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Updated the proposal to incorporate your suggestion. Thanks !!!

Comment: To all: If any of you know any specific tags to be attached to the question, please feel free.

Comment: The whole question should be in text form. Images should only be used for when they are necessary (binary data, demonstrating layout). So I think this is a general requirement and does not only apply for this close reason but everywhere. I would therefore put it on "How to ask..." and refer to that all the time.

Comment: It's still a big blob of text.  I'd like to see a numbered list of items that should be included in the question.  "You're missing #3."

Comment: Why not make this a [tag:feature-request]?

Comment: @TylerH I'm not very sure whether this can be called a _feature_ or not. Possible improvement, is what I can say.However, if you see fit, please add that.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The way I see it, any time you are requesting something be added to the site (which this qualifies as, IMO), it is a feature request :-)

Comment: @TylerH Ok, makes sense. Let me add that then.

Comment: I've  personally never seen this. It's so much harder to put a screenshot in vs just cutting and pasting code I have to believe this is an edge case.

Comment: @theMayer It's not only about screenshot, but links also. And yes, This happens a lot, believe me.

Comment: And it's not just screen captures: I've even seen photos, presumably taken using a phone. OTOH, I must admit these are rather rare on SO, but fairly common on SE.Mathematics where they're used as a substitute for posting equations using LaTeX code.

Comment: The best is when you see a jsfiddle link posted as code so the OP gets around the post the code quality filter.

Comment: Anyone else think the kind of people who would post screenshots of code in the question are the same kind of people you'd see on Clients from Hell?

Comment: Doesn't the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) cover this? Particularly the _"Complete"_ section containing the following: _"Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included: Some people might be prepared to load the parts up, and actually try them to test the answer they're about to post. If the problem requires some server-side code as well as an XML-based configuration file, include them both. If a web page problem requires HTML, some JavaScript and a stylesheet, include all three."_ You can't load an image

Comment: @SouravGhosh "this will save me from leaving a separate comment" don't bother, just vote to close and move on. These questions are rarely worth any more effort.

Comment: I am not at all sure this would work. Too subtle! Why not include the text "... and not as a screenshot" in the close reason.

Comment: @Raedwald If we can do that _and_ educate the misguided OP at the same time about the error of their ways, that would be lovely.

Comment: @the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932710/returning-structure-but-compiler-shows-that-the-function-returns-integer is just one of many recent examples

Comment: Umm.. Proposal? Dosen't it mean something else? Like [This](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=proposal&rlz=1C1CHMO_enIN672IN672&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB_42Y-7rLAhWDU44KHTt5An8Q_AUIBygB&biw=1242&bih=619#imgrc=2d1kkcZqGH5iWM%3A) And the funny thing is you wrote `I propose` No offence Intended

Comment: @Mr.Helpy It _also_ means something else. google.com says "a plan or suggestion, especially a formal or written one, put forward for consideration or discussion by others" as its first dictionary definition. Edit: oh, so does google.co.in.

Comment: @Mr.Helpy How ironic!! This post is _against_ adding the images, and your given link point to the result of, well, _image search._ :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Well, honestly I didn't read the post. But your comment really amuses me.

Comment: Someone still looking for examples? [here's a live one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36203668/2173917).

Comment: [and this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37820623/2173917)

Answer (score 6):

The only problem about this suggestion is that some languages are not textual, so it is impossible to include them in textual form.

I agree that this change makes sense for most situations, but I think we need to be careful we're not scaring away legitimate questions.

Fortunately, graphical languages are a small and well-behaved minority, as far as I've seen.

I think that we need to be clear that it would only apply to text that is in a picture, not strictly code. By saying "no pictures of text", it would also cover those cases where it's the stack trace or the contents of a database that are in the picture, neither of which would apply with the proposed wording.

Of course, we should allow pictures of text when it is both supplementary and relevant to the problem stated in the question. An example of this would be typography issues.

---

Here's what Scratch looks like, BTW:

[image: here's teh codez]

Comment: Right. _"The only problem about this suggestion is that some languages are not textual, so it is impossible to include them in textual form."_ So, **those** question do not **require** the "code" to be present in text form and thus, excluded form the close category, is not it?

Comment: We **only** need to close those questions which can and need to have the   textual code to reproduce the problem, that's the basic target of this discussion. :)