# Require image of Scratch script for Scratch questions

Tags: feature-request, code, rules

It's hard to visualize a script in visual programming language like Scratch. Here's an example of what I mean:

> The correct way to make an infinite loop without the `forever` block is to use the `repeat` block, with the amount of times to repeat at something like `999999999999999999999999999`. Here's an example script of what you should do:
>
> ```
> repeat (999999999999999999999999999)
>     ...
> ```

*(ignore the broken formatting)*

Plus, you can't do C loops like shown above.

Instead, there should be a rule so you'd have to do this:

> The correct way to make an infinite loop without the `forever` block is to use the `repeat` block, with the amount of times to repeat at something like `999999999999999999999999999`. Here's an example script of what you should do:
>
> [image: Scratch block example image]

It is much more easier to read and understand that.

There is even [a tool](https://scratchblocks.github.io/) that allows you to make an image like the one in the example. You can see the tool with that example [here](https://scratchblocks.github.io/#repeat%20(999999999999999999999999999)%0A...%0Aend). You can export the thing as a .PNG then upload it to Imgur.

I propose there to be a rule requiring images of the Scratch blocks, not just code, for all [mit-scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mit-scratch) questions and answers.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325611

Comment: Adding an image is probably a good idea.  But we don't even require code for all questions, why would we require code and image for one specific language?

Comment: How would this work for users without permissions to add images to their posts?

Comment: There could be an exemption for questions ragged with Mir-scratch on here.

Answer (score 10):

The tool you are referring to is also available as a library which can be used in a snippet:

```html
<script src="https://github.com/scratchblocks/scratchblocks/releases/download/v3.5.2/scratchblocks-v3.5.2-min.js"></script>

<pre class="blocks">
when green flag clicked
repeat [42]
  say [This is the answer.]
end
</pre>

<script>
scratchblocks.renderMatching('pre.blocks', {style: 'scratch3'});
</script>
```

---

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68696376/1244884) of mine for a more complex example.